# Java housework ,a simple logic

Tags: java

```
package Easy;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Demo1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {2, 7, 11, 15};
        int t = 26;
        int[] arr = twoSum(nums, t);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));//printout is supposed to be [2,3],however it's [3, 4],what's wrong?
    }
    public static int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        int[] result = new int[2];  
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(target - numbers[i])) {
                result[1] = i + 1;
                result[0] = map.get(target - numbers[i]);
                return result;
            }
            map.put(numbers[i], i + 1);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

printout is supposed to be [2,3],however it's [3, 4],what's wrong?thank you for your help.

description:
    Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

```
You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:
Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].
```

Comment: `map.put(numbers[i], i)` instead of `i+1`?   Also `result[1] = i`  instead of `i+1`?

Comment: Arrays in Java have indexes starting with 0.  So `nums[2]` is 11 and `nums[3]` is 15, and that's why the output is supposed to be 2 and 3.  But your code is adding 1 in a couple places as if the indexes started at 1.  Your code would be working correctly if indexes started with 1.

Comment: Hint: when you don't understand what your code is doing add print statements to enable you to observe what happens. Or use a debugger. You don't need other people for those steps.

Comment: If you're intending to become a professional programmer, then learning to use a debugger will save you _weeks_, possibly even _years_ of your time, in the course of your career.  It's something you should learn as soon as you possibly can.

Answer (score 0):

your way is complicated you can solve it in more simple approach:

```
  int[] nums = {2, 7, 11, 15};
  ArrayList<Integer> index = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  int t = 26;
  for(int i=0 ; i < nums.length-1 ; i++){
      for(int j=i+1 ; j < nums.length ; j++){
          if(nums[i] + nums[j] == t){
               index.add(i);
               index.add(j);
          }
      }
  }
    System.out.println(index);
```

output:

```
[2, 3]
```

check it: https://ideone.com/jM1wJQ